# Illegal reflective access to method java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.cleaner()

Tags: java

I am using [jpdfbookmarks](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpdfbookmarks/) with 2.5.2 version.

```
$ jpdfbookmarks_cli spec.pdf -dump -o orig.jpdf
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.lowagie.text.pdf.MappedRandomAccessFile$1 (file:/home/t/program_files/document/bookmark/jpdfbookmarks-2.5.2/lib/iText-2.1.7-patched.jar) to method java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.cleaner()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.lowagie.text.pdf.MappedRandomAccessFile$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

I was wondering how to avoid the problems in the warnings?

Thanks.